# validate method in backbone.js is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am learning `backbone.js`, using a `validate` method in it. But it is not getting triggered at `set`
following is my code:

JS:

```
var person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
        name:"Soni",
        age:'40',
        work:'Still searching'
    },
    mainWork: function(mainwork) {
        return this.get('name')+" does "+mainwork+" for living";
    },
    validate: function(attrs) {
            console.log("hi");
        if (attrs.age < 1) {
            return "can't end before it starts";
        }
    }
});
```

on console:

```
var x = new person({name:'xyz',age:37});
x.set('age',-34);
```

please tell me, what am I missing here.

Answer (score 3):

Validate method will be called on model `save`. If you want to trigger it on attribute `set` you should call it will validate: true option:

```
x.set({age: -34}, {validate: true});
```

Comment: I was watching a screen cast on Nettus, that guy was saying that it works on `set` method. even on his screen cast, at time of set method execution, validation was working.

Comment: Well, what can I say, I only know that by default it will work if you pass validate:true option. http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate

Comment: I should official website then... thnx for your help :)